# Block SSH tunneling to IP, allow only for certain users

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I need to setup SSH to block all access to a certain IP on port 555. Only a small group of users should be allowed to tunnel to that IP. Currently I have the following stuff in my sshd_config

```
Match User bob
        PermitOpen 1.2.3.4:555 5.6.7.8:555
```

The question I have is, how do I deny all other users access to this tunnel? I dont see a denyopen, or restrictopen thing in sshd_config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with a firewall on the SSH box:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 555 -m owner --uid-owner bob -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 555                          -j REJECT
```

Comment: Just tested it out, works!.
Thanks!

Comment: +1 This is even better than the SSH solution which was restricting SSH only, and not programs executed through SSH.

Answer (score 11):

Disable TcpForwarding for all users by default:

```
AllowTcpForwarding No
```

And make an exception for user `bob`:

```
Match User bob
        AllowTcpForwarding Yes
        PermitOpen 1.2.3.4:555 5.6.7.8:555
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to allow tunneling to anywhere other than those.

Comment: From [`man sshd_config`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/): "PermitOpen: **Specifies the destinations to which TCP port forwarding is permitted.** [..] An argument of "any" can be used to remove all restrictions and permit any forwarding requests.  **By default all port forwarding requests are permitted.**", this is my interpretation of his question.

Comment: Right, but my interpretation is the OP wants `PermitOpen !1.2.3.4:555` by default, not `AlloqTCPForwarding off`.  Guess we wait for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, so what I want is:

All users to be able to tunnel everywhere EXCEPT for 1.2.3.4.5:555.

Only certain users should be allowed to tunnel there.
The problem with this solution is that if I then do 
 
         Match User {enter all users here}
              AllowTCPForwarding Yes

They will have access to that IP as well. That being said its still a very good answer :)

It might very well need firewall rules on the otherside.